# How do I define database project dependencies at publication time?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am working on bringing an application comprised of several SqlServer databases into a source control system. I've come up with a solution using several project files, each representing one of the databases, but in order for it to compile, the database project references need to be defined for several database projects, or I get errors regarding missing dependencies and the like. With the references set up, the solution compiles ok.

However, with the solution publishing, I will need to publish the referenced database projects first if I don't want to get 'Invalid object name' script publishing errors on their referencing projects. I would like to have this configured and be able to publish by just clicking on the 'publish solution' button. Is there a way to define 'publication dependencies', similar to the compilation dependencies, that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this - had to turn off transactions (so I wouldn't roll back), then publish several times. In my instance, I only had one DB that required that, but I had to:

1. Publish DB A
2. Publish DBs B/C/D/E
3. Re-publish DB A to catch the rest of the objects.

I had a special Publish profile set up that did not use transactions just for this purpose. Other than that, you're probably going to have to keep some sort of track about dependencies if you create a lot of new objects that depend on other databases.

I have not come across any publication dependencies so far, but it would be helpful to have something like that to avoid these sorts of issues.